# React Native:How to change dynamic view borderColor colour?

Tags: react-native

I have created 5 Text programatically in react native .
I want to change the borderColor colour of view By click item.
I tried using below code .But its changing all 5 views borderColor colour .
I want change borderColor colour of only one view.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      pills.push (this.renderPill (i));
    }


 renderPill (index) {
return (
  <TouchableOpacity key={index} style={ this.state.status ? boxStyle : boxStyleSelected } onPress={this.itemClick.bind(this)}>
    <View >
      <Text>
        {index}
      </Text>
    </View>
  </TouchableOpacity>

);


  }
}
multiItemClick (index) {

    this.setState({ status: true });

  }

    boxStyle: {

    borderColor: '#ffffff',


  },
  boxStyleSelected: {

    borderColor: '#000000',


  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that you are using the state for all views. Try to modify the code to something, that depends on the index you clicked.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      pills.push (this.renderPill (i));
    }


 renderPill (index) {
return (
  <TouchableOpacity key={index} style={ this.state.status[index] ? boxStyle : boxStyleSelected } onPress={(index) => this.itemClick(index)}>
    <View >
      <Text>
        {index}
      </Text>
    </View>
  </TouchableOpacity>

);

itemClick(index) {
let status = this.state;
status[index] = true;
this.setState({
   status: status   
})
```

I have not tested this, so I am not 100% sure about the syntax, but i think the idea is clear. You have to save wich item is clicked in an array, so you know what item has to be rendered with the different border.

But I also would really advice to use a `FlatList` here https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html Because what you are trying to do is render a clickable List. That will give you way more control over the items, their direct styling and the list container. Also you would not need to have two separate lists, but could use an array of objects like this

```
{
   value: 1
   clicked: true
}
```

which makes it more readable and maintainable.

edit: there is actually a code sample for a multiselect on the link provided, i adapted it to your pills. Just hand the array to the component from somewhere else. Id and title is needed. View looks like this:

[image: Example]

Code goes like this:

```
export default class MyView extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            pills: [{id: 1, title: 'Pill 1'},
                    {id: 2, title: 'Pill 2'},
                    {id: 3, title: 'Pill 3'}],
        };
    }

    render() {
        const {pills} = this.state;
        return (
            <MultiSelectList data={pills}/>
        );
    }

}

class MultiSelectList extends React.PureComponent {
    state = {selected: (new Map())};

    _keyExtractor = (item, index) => item.id;

    _onPressItem = (id) => {
        // updater functions are preferred for transactional updates
        this.setState((state) => {
            // copy the map rather than modifying state.
            const selected = new Map(state.selected);
            selected.set(id, !selected.get(id)); // toggle
            return {selected};
        });
    };

    _renderItem = ({item}) => (
        <MyListItem
            id={item.id}
            onPressItem={this._onPressItem}
            selected={!!this.state.selected.get(item.id)}
            title={item.title}
        />);

    render() {
        return (
            <FlatList
                data={this.props.data}
                extraData={this.state}
                keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor}
                renderItem={this._renderItem}
            />
        );
    }
}

class MyListItem extends React.PureComponent {
    _onPress = () => {
        this.props.onPressItem(this.props.id);
    };

    render() {
        const color = this.props.selected ? "red" : "black";
        return (
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={this._onPress}>
                <View>
                    <Text style={{borderStyle: 'solid', borderWidth: 2, borderColor: color }}>
                        {this.props.title}
                    </Text>
                </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: this.state.status[index]  is undefined inside renderPill

Comment: I was thinking the status was defined around it. Can not tell for sure as i do not have the whole class. In the constructor status must also be an array. After all, a flatlist is really what you should be using.

Comment: I will post a flatlist example, when i am on a pc again. I am on mobile right now.

Comment: I added the sample wich goes with your pills array. This is producing the view you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You should use **FlatList** to render your item or component list.

> Here are an Example:

```
render() {
return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <FlatList
      data={ this.state.listItem }
      ItemSeparatorComponent = {this._itemSeparator}
      keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
      renderItem={this._renderItem}
      selected={this.state.selected}
    />
  </View>  
);}
```

> Separate the item list

```
_itemSeparator = () => (<View style={{ height: 1, backgroundColor: "#607D8B" }}/>);
```

> Render the Item list

```
_renderItem = (item) => {
return (
  <TouchableOpacity 
    key={item.index} 
    style={this.state.selected == item.index ? styles.boxSelected : styles.boxStyle} 
    onPress={()=>this._itemClick(item)}
  >
    <View style={{alignItems:'center'}}>
      <Text>
        {item.item.key}
      </Text>
    </View>
  </TouchableOpacity>
);}
```

> Event on Click item to Change the Style

```
_itemClick(item) { this.setState({selected:item.index}) }
```

> Data State

```
constructor(props){
super(props);

this.state = { 
  selected: null,
  listItem: [
    {key: 'One'},
    {key: 'Two'},
    {key: 'Three'},
    {key: 'Four'},
    {key: 'Five'},
    {key: 'Six'},
    {key: 'Seven'},
    {key: 'Eight'},
    {key: 'Nine'},
    {key: 'Ten'},
    {key: 'Eleven'},
    {key: 'Twelve'}
  ]
};}
```

> Style Sheet your item

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({ 
  container :{
    justifyContent: 'center',
    flex:1,
    margin: 10,
    paddingTop:50
  },
  boxStyle: {
    backgroundColor: '#778788',
    padding: 10,
    margin:3
  },
  boxSelected: {
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    padding: 10,
    margin:3
  }
});
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMtcH.png)

This is what i got for you, Hope it will save your time.